# run bash script for each files in folder

Tags: python, bash, ffmpeg

i found this script but it need input filename and output filename to work

i'm windows user so i dont know how to run this script for each files in folder

what i want is :

sourcefile=$1 -> this should be input directory
destfile=$2 -> output directory or just originalfilename_preview

so when i'm try to excute script, it will run through files in input directory and excute two ffmpeg script inside

the first ffmpeg script will split video into multiple files in temp folder
the second ffmpeg merge those files in temp folder and complete the whole process with output folder or originalfilename_preview

-> loop for next files until completed

```
sourcefile=$1
destfile=$2

# Overly simple validation
if [ ! -e "$sourcefile" ]; then
  echo 'Please provide an existing input file.'
  exit
fi

if [ "$destfile" == "" ]; then
  echo 'Please provide an output preview file name.'
  exit
fi

# Get video length in seconds
length=$(ffprobe $sourcefile  -show_format 2>&1 | sed -n 's/duration=//p' | awk '{print int($0)}')

# Start 20 seconds into the video to avoid opening credits (arbitrary)
starttimeseconds=20

# Mini-snippets will be 2 seconds in length
snippetlengthinseconds=2

# We'll aim for 5 snippets spread throughout the video
desiredsnippets=5

# Ensure the video is long enough to even bother previewing
minlength=$(($snippetlengthinseconds*$desiredsnippets))

# Video dimensions (these could probably be command line arguments)
dimensions=640:-1

# Temporary directory and text file where we'll store snippets
# These will be cleaned up and removed when the preview image is generated
tempdir=snippets
listfile=list.txt

# Display and check video length
echo 'Video length: ' $length
if [ "$length" -lt "$minlength" ]
then
  echo 'Video is too short.  Exiting.'
  exit
fi

# Loop and generate video snippets
mkdir $tempdir
interval=$(($length/$desiredsnippets-$starttimeseconds))
for i in $(seq 1 $desiredsnippets)
do
    # Format the second marks into hh:mm:ss format
    start=$(($(($i*$interval))+$starttimeseconds))
    formattedstart=$(printf "%02d:%02d:%02d\n" $(($start/3600)) $(($start%3600/60)) $(($start%60)))
    echo 'Generating preview part ' $i $formattedstart
    # Generate the snippet at calculated time
    ffmpeg -i $sourcefile -vf scale=$dimensions -preset fast -qmin 1 -qmax 1 -ss $formattedstart -t $snippetlengthinseconds -threads $(nproc) $tempdir/$i.mp4
done

# Concat videos
echo 'Generating final preview file'

# Generate a text file with one snippet video location per line
# (https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate)
for f in $tempdir/*; do echo "file '$f'" >> $listfile; done

# Concatenate the files based on the generated list
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i $listfile -threads $(nproc) -an -tune zerolatency -x264opts bitrate=2000:vbv-maxrate=2000:vbv-bufsize=166 -vcodec libx264 -f mpegts -muxrate 2000K -y $destfile.mp4

echo 'Done!  Check ' $destfile '.mp4!'

# Cleanup
rm -rf $tempdir $listfile
```

source: https://davidwalsh.name/video-preview

@Christopher Hoffman
wsl already installed, of course, i'm already run this script without problem but i need to manual input/output filename

```
./preview.sh input.mp4 out
```

@Renaud Pacalet

1. yes, all files in input directory or drag&drop files (but all files
   in directory seem like easier)
2. i think modify script
3. output file have suffix in name "_preview"
4. if it have suffix, same input folder is ok,
5. video files (mkv,mp4,avi,..)
6. some files name have unicode character so i think input file will
   inside " "

Comment: First you have to run an linux distrobution in windows: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/ubuntu-on-windows#1-overview

Comment: What you ask for is not 100% clear to me. Do you want to modify this script such that it processes all files in a directory? Or do you want to keep the script as it is and run it on all files in a directory? And for an input file named, e.g., `foo.mp4`, how do you want to name the output? Same name but in a different directory? `foo_preview.mp4` in the same directory? Finally, what input files do you want to process? All files named `something.mp4` in the input directory? Other? Please answer all this by editing your question. No comments, images, external links. Just edit your question.

Comment: @Christopher Hoffman
wsl already installed, of course, i'm already run this script without problem but i need to manual input/output filename

Comment: manual input in script is `read varname`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest is probably to keep the script as it is and to use a bash loop to process all files in the input directory. Let's assume:

- the input directory is `/my/video/files`,
- you want to store all outputs in directory `/some/where`,
- the script you show is in `/else/where/myscript.sh`,
- you want to process **all** files in the input directory.

Just open a terminal where `bash` is the interactive shell and type:

```sh
shopt -s nullglob
chmod +x /else/where/myscript.sh
mkdir -p /some/where
cd /my/video/files
for f in *; do
  /else/where/myscript.sh "$f" "/some/where/$f"
done
shopt -u nullglob
```

Explanations:

- `shopt -s nullglob` enables the `nullglob` option. Without this, if there are no files at all in the input directory, there would still be one iteration of the loop with `f=*`. `shopt -u nullglob` disables it when we are done.
- `chmod +x /else/where/myscript.sh` makes your script executable, just in case it was not already.
- `mkdir -p /some/where` creates the output directory, just in case it did not exist yet.
- `cd /my/video/files` changes the current directory to the input directory in which you have your video files.
- `for f in *; do` loops over all files in the current directory (this is what the `*` stands for). In each iteration variable `f` is assigned the current file name.
- `/else/where/myscript.sh "$f" "/some/where/$f"` executes your script with two parameters: the name of the input file and the name of the output file, both quoted with double quotes to prevent word splitting.

Note: if all files are not video files you can be more specific:

```sh
for f in *.mkv *.mp4 *.avi; do
  ...
```

Of course, for easier reuse, you can also create a new shell script file with all this.

Comment: thank you, so i'm tried this way and it work :
for X in ./*.mp4; do ./preview.sh "${X}" "${X}_preview"; done   .    BUT output filename is blank

Comment: What do you mean _output filename is blank_? The loop creates only one file which name is blank? I don't understand. Do you mean that the generated files don't have the `.mp4` extension and that you cannot see them with the graphical user interface of your video tool? If yes, it's normal: you generated `foo.mp4_preview` from `foo.mp4`. It's thus not considered as a video file. Try `./preview.sh "${X}" "preview_${X}"`, instead.

Comment: oh filename is blank because i'm edited filename inside script, it work now :
for X in ./*.mp4; do ./preview.sh "${X}" "${X}_preview"; done .

1- But if my video name is 1.mp4, output will be 1.mp4_preview.mp4, is there have anyway to remove extension after original filename ? so it will be 1_preview.mp4 instead
2 - look like preview.sh script cannot work with unicode filename (chinese,etc.)
eg : 水曜日のカンパネラ『バッキンガム』

Comment: 1) Try `./preview.sh "${X}" "${X%.mp4}_preview`, this will remove the trailing`.mp4` from the value of `X`. 2) What happens with unicode filenames?

Comment: oh it worked, after installed language pack. thank you

Comment: but look like script preview.sh cannot work with filename have space (123 123,123 , 123)

Comment: Yes, double quotes are missing around several variable expansions. Add them at least around every `$sourcefile` and `$destfile`.

Comment: yeah, i already did that after my last comment.